# Can I get the shape of a numpy save file without reading the entire contents (e.g. memmap)

Tags: python, numpy

I have a large numpy file saved to disk, I would like to determine the shape without reading in the entire file.

I can get the shape using `np.load(filename)`, but when I try the same using `np.memmap` appears to require that I know the shape in advance, otherwise it defaults to reading the file in a flat array of `uint8` values.

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Yes](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/neps/nep-0001-npy-format.rst#format-specification-version-10), you will find the shape in plain-text in the first line of the file:

```
>>> a = np.random.rand(4,7)
>>> np.save('/tmp/a', a)
>>>
$ head -1 /tmp/a.npy
�NUMPYv{'descr': '<f8', 'fortran_order': False, 'shape': (4, 7), }
```

Here is the code to parse this header:

```
>>> with open('/tmp/a.npy', 'rb') as f:
...     major, minor = np.lib.format.read_magic(f)
...     shape, fortran, dtype = np.lib.format.read_array_header_1_0(f)
...     
>>> shape
(4, 7)
```

Answer (score 5):

np.memmap is generally for binary files, but np.load has the ability to load .npy files in memmap mode. No shape or dtype needed! Try:

```
mmapped_array = np.load(filename, mmap_mode='r')
```

Comment: Oh, fabulous, this is an excellent answer. Unlucky for me, it doesn't support object dtype's. I get the error `ValueError: Array can't be memory-mapped: Python objects in dtype.`

Comment: Yeah I can see how memmapping Objects would be a no-go. Objects, after all, do not have a determined shape/size/stride in memory. This is in opposition to a numeric ctypes like an int8 or float64 which are 1 or 8 bytes long.

Comment: wim answered the question in the title, wilson answered what we came here for.